# app.auth is not a function error in firebase react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

Im trying to connect firebase with a react app, but I get the `Uncaught TypeError: app.auth is not a function` error when trying to create an auth variable  `export const auth = app.auth()`

This is the code:

```
import firebase from 'firebase/compat/app';
import 'firebase/auth';

const app = firebase.initializeApp({
    apiKey: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_API_KEY,
    authDomain: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN,
    projectId: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID,
    storageBucket: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET,
    messagingSenderId: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID,
    appId: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_APP_ID
})

export const auth = app.auth()
export default app;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `getAuth` instead of `app.auth`:

```
import firebase from 'firebase/compat/app';
import {getAuth} from 'firebase/auth';

const app = firebase.initializeApp({
    ...
})

export const auth = getAuth()
export default app;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the namespaced syntax then you must import `compat` version of Firebase Auth SDK as well.

```
import firebase from 'firebase/compat/app';
import 'firebase/compat/auth'; // <-- add /compat/
```

> The `compat` libraries are a temporary solution that will be removed completely in a future major SDK version (such as version 10 or version 11). Your ultimate goal is to remove `compat` code and keep only version 9 modular-style code in your app.

Checkout the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/modular-upgrade) for more information.